# Ruby: empty string and empty string, what is the difference?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Novice question, I make attempt debug bug in ruby application,
you can see it [here](http://www.redmine.org/issues/20192).

The code:

```
def self.default_url_options
    options = {:protocol => Setting.protocol}
    if Setting.host_name.to_s =~ /\A(https?\:\/\/)?(.+?)(\:(\d+))?(\/.+)?\z/i
      host, port, prefix = $2, $4, $5
      options.merge!({
        :host => host, :port => port, :script_name => prefix
      })
    else
      options[:host] = Setting.host_name
    end
    options
  end
```

if I add logging after `host, port, prefix = $2, $4, $5`:

```
  host, port, prefix = $2, $4, $5
  Rails.logger.error "!!!!!!! '#{host}', '#{port}', '#{prefix}'"
```

I got:
!!!!!!! 'hostname.net', '', ''

so `prefix` is empty, but if set `:script_name` explicitly to `''`
the behavior of program changed and I got expected result, in
another words:

```
:script_name => ''
```

and empty `$5` gives different results.

1. **What is the difference between empty `$5` and empty string?**
2. **What is proper fix for this issue from ruby programmer point of view?**

Comment: empty `$5` means `nil`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there is no match, `$5` becomes `nil`, not empty string. What you see in logger is `nil.to_s`, which is apparently, an empty string.

But in `options`, `nil` and empty string have different meanings. `nil` means “no port set”, while empty string means “port set to empty string,” resulting in smth like:

```
#                 ⇓⇓ here is empty port!
http://example.com:/path
```

which makes the whole thing to fail.